# How to get AD user for Azure subscription Classic Administrators?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

My goal is to get the Azure AD users who have been assigned the Classic Administrator role in an azure subscription.
I use the REST api's [Classic Administrators - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/classicadministrators/list) to retrieve all classic admins but it returns an Email which is not unique enough and an ID called netId/puid which is not present on the [user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta) returned from the Graph API.

I followed the Azure Portal's network to see how it gets the users for AAD but it queries the Graph API with an internal API version '1.61-internal' that I can't use.

Does anyone know on a way to retrieve this information?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can go to azure portal -> subscription -> your target sub -> access control -> Classic adminsitrators to see all the users who has this role. By the way, you may use fiddler to catch the http request to gather how the website get these users.

Comment: Like I stated in my question the http request the portal does uses an API version "1.61-internal" that I am unable to use from my application, The supported version (1.6) does not return the values I need :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an exposed API to match netId/puid with users.

But you can get the `puid` from the access token.

Or you could use [Microsoft 365 Powershell cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0) `Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "{upn}" | fl` to get the user and find the `LiveId` property.

Record the `puid` or `LiveId` above and the corresponding user information to your local configuration file and match them with the `name` property in response of [Classic Administrators - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/classicadministrators/list).

Then you can get the corresponding users who are classic Administrators.

It's just a workaround and there are many workloads. I don't think it is a good method but there is no other way.

Comment: Well I was hoping for a way to resolve according to the puid itself.. Getting the LiveId from m365 by UPN will be the same as asking the Graph for the principal by the UPN.
So are you sure there is no way of getting it?

Comment: @Nitmetic As you see the Graph user resource type, there is not a property called netId/puid/liveid. And only the internal API can return the property. Based on it, there is no exposed API.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll hope they add the ability.. I opened a [feature request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/42544969-add-support-to-get-the-azure-ad-users-that-are-sub) and a [Graph API issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/11422).